# Calculate row similarity percentage pair wise and add it as a new column

Tags: r, datatable, tidyverse, similarity

I have a date frame like this sample, I would like to find similar rows (not duplicate) and calculate similarity per wise. I find [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52650932/how-to-calculate-the-similarity-for-all-the-rows-in-a-table-in-r) but i would like to keep all my columns and add similarity percentage as a new variable. My aim is to find records with highest similarity percentage. How could I do it ?

## sample data set

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
     ~date, ~user_id, ~Station_id, ~location_id, ~ind_id, ~start_hour, ~start_minute, ~start_second, ~end_hour, ~end_minute, ~end_second, ~duration_min,
  20191015, 19900234,         242,            2,    "ac",           7,            25,             0,         7,          30,          59,             6,
  20191015, 19900234,         242,            2,    "ac",           7,            31,             0,         7,          32,          59,             2,
  20191015, 19900234,         242,            2,    "ac",           7,            33,             0,         7,          38,          59,             6,
  20191015, 19900234,         242,            2,    "ac",           7,            39,             0,         7,          40,          59,             2,
  20191015, 19900234,         242,            2,    "ac",           7,            41,             0,         7,          43,          59,             3,
  20191015, 19900234,         242,            2,    "ac",           7,            44,             0,         7,          45,          59,             2,
  20191015, 19900234,         242,            2,    "ac",           7,            47,             0,         7,          59,          59,            13,
  20191015, 19900234,         242,            2,    "ad",           7,            47,             0,         7,          59,          59,            13,
  20191015, 19900234,         242,            2,    "ac",           8,             5,             0,         8,           6,          59,             2,
  20191015, 19900234,         242,            2,    "ad",           8,             5,             0,         8,           6,          59,             2,
  20191015, 19900234,         242,            2,    "ac",           8,             7,             0,         8,           8,          59,             2,
  20191015, 19900234,         242,            2,    "ad",           8,             7,             0,         8,           8,          59,             2,
  20191015, 19900234,         242,            2,    "ac",          16,            26,             0,        16,          55,          59,            30,
  20191015, 19900234,         242,            2,    "ad",          16,            26,             0,        16,          55,          59,            30,
  20191015, 19900234,         242,            2,    "ad",          17,             5,             0,        17,           6,          59,             2,
  20191015, 19900234,         242,            2,    "ac",          17,             5,             0,        17,          23,          59,            19,
  20191015, 19900234,         242,            2,    "ad",          17,             7,             0,        17,          15,          59,             9,
  20191015, 19900234,         242,            2,    "ad",          17,            16,             0,        17,          22,          59,             7,
  20191015, 19900234,         264,            2,    "ac",          17,            24,             0,        17,          35,          59,            12,
  20191015, 19900234,         264,            2,    "ad",          17,            25,             0,        17,          35,          59,            11,
  20191016, 19900234,         242,            1,    "ac",           7,            12,             0,         7,          14,          59,             3,
  20191016, 19900234,         242,            1,    "ad",           7,            13,             0,         7,          13,          59,             1,
  20191016, 19900234,         242,            1,    "ac",          17,            45,             0,        17,          49,          59,             5,
  20191016, 19900234,         242,            1,    "ad",          17,            46,             0,        17,          48,          59,             3,
  20191016, 19900234,         242,            2,    "ad",           7,            14,             0,         8,           0,          59,            47,
  20191016, 19900234,         242,            2,    "ac",           7,            15,             0,         8,           0,          59,            47
  )
```

## Function for comparing rows

```
row_cf <- function(x, y, df){
  sum(df[x,] == df[y,])/ncol(df)
}
```

## Function output

```
# 1) Create all possible row combinations
# 2) Rename 
# 3) Run through each row
# 4) Calculate similarity

expand.grid(1:nrow(df), 1:nrow(df)) %>% 
  rename(row_1 = Var1, row_2 = Var2) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(similarity = row_cf(row_1, row_2, df))


# A tibble: 676 x 3
   row_1 row_2 similarity
   <int> <int>      <dbl>
 1     1     1      1    
 2     2     1      0.75 
 3     3     1      0.833
 4     4     1      0.75 
 5     5     1      0.75 
 6     6     1      0.75 
 7     7     1      0.75 
 8     8     1      0.667
 9     9     1      0.583
10    10     1      0.5
```

Edit:
I would like to find similar rows in the data like here
[image]

Comment: just to clarify, you have 26 rows in the example data, and would calculate 26x26 = 676 similarity values (pairwise comparisons) -  did you want a final dataframe to have 676 rows, and for each similarity value, add columns of perhaps selected variables from the original data frame? Could you provide what your final desired output should look like in the end?

Comment: @ben my aim is to find similar rows , I edited the question. It may need not to calculate 676 similarity values. I am interested to flag similar rows. let say if if arrange / sort the data so if row 2 is similar to row 3 (similar not duplicated) then I flag it either with similarity rate or another way

Comment: Do you only want the most similar row? You'll still need to make all the comparisons (26 * 25, actually, since you don't need to compare a row to itself). But do you want, say, to add 2 new columns giving the most similar row and also giving its similarity score? Or something else?

Comment: @Gregor yes, having the most similar row with its similarity score is what I am looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your "function output", call it `sim`. Eliminate the self-comparisons and then keep the max similarity row grouped by row_1:

```
sim = sim %>% 
  filter(row_1 != row_2) %>%
  group_by(row_1) %>% 
  slice(which.max(similarity))
```

Then you can add these to your original data:

```
df %>% mutate(row_1 = 1:n()) %>%
  left_join(sim)
```

The `row_2` column gives the row number of the most similar row, and `similarity` gives its similarity score. (You may want to improve these column names.)

Comment: what you are referring as a self-comparisons in "function output"?

Comment: Any time a row is compare to itself. Like the first row, where `row_1 = 1` and `row_2 = 1`, and your similarity column tells use that the first row has a score of `1` compared to itself. That's useless.