# R: Use classification method to sort out clustering outcomes over many iterations

Tags: r, classification, cluster-analysis

So I have some data and I run cluster method to segment the samples into 4 clusters.Now I tested the stability of those clusters by running the clustering algorithm a few hundred times with a 10% dropout rate except the first run, run1.

Let's assume the output like below

```
Sample <- LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 20 )]
run_1 <- rep(1:4, each=5)
run_2 <- c(rep(1:2, each=4),rep(3:4,6))
run_3 <- rep(4:1, each=5)
run_4 <- c(rep(4:3, each=4),rep(1:2,6))

df <- data.frame(cbind(Sample, run_1,run_2,run_3,run_4))
```

[image]

Because in each run, the cluster ID number is randomly assigned, so sample ABCDE are in cluster 1 in run 1 but cluster 4 run 3 .... etc.

I want to use run 1 as a membership reference, and to build a classifier so that I can sort out in the rest of hundreds of runs, what run_X_cluster_ Y are effectively the cluster 1 in run 1.

My challenge is I thought of using sample ID to track, but in certain runs, not all samples always stay together, for example E some times leave his partners, in run_2 E joins cluster2, which is effectively the run_1_cluster2.  so if I track all sample E and classify based on them being E are in the run_1 cluster_1, I lose that information. So how should I classify them?

The end goal I'm thinking is to effectively renaming and uniting the cluster IDs over all my runs with reference to run_1, so all cluster 1 means the same cluster. Then I can calculate how frequent each sample stays in a cluster.

I'm scratching my head at the moment. if there is a better way, please also enlighten me

Comment: First you need to decide what you are going to use as a measure of "stability". For example, you could compute the centroids for each cluster in each run and then use kmeans to cluster the centroids into four groups. The variability within each group could be taken as a measure of "stability."

Comment: Hi @dcarlson, actually we did the test and found 4 clusters are stable, and indeed used something like variability (sd) to see that. Now I want to know across all the hundreds of runs, what are my samples that most likely to stay together in one of the 4 clusters. for example I want to figure out if 100% the time sample A B and C stay in the same cluster, but probably 50% E  stay with them.

Comment: actually, can't I just use KNN to sort them out? treating each iteration a variable..

Comment: Yes I think so. I was thinking you could use each cluster in each run as an observation so 100 runs times 4 clusters using the centroids of each cluster to define it. Define each of these by the run number/cluster number so you can get back to the original clusters and create a table of the number of times each original observation fell into that cluster. Probably best to try this with 10 runs to figure out the best way to do it.

Comment: @dcarlson great suggestion, thank you :)

Comment: On the other side, I thought I might be able to do a rowwise similarity comparison, ignoring the so-called ground truth of run_0, and see how that turns out. found out this gem, and the function is pretty much what I needhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/58426599/calculate-row-similarity-percentage-pair-wise-and-add-it-as-a-new-colum

Comment: @dcarlson so I wrote another one here to explain myself. thank you for your patience https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66319416/r-compute-the-row-wise-similarity-for-a-dataframe-and-sort-data-out-based-on-th